# How to calculate the highest number and compare it to the average?

Tags: java, for-loop, if-statement, double, calculation

This is what I am trying to do:

the user needs to enter 4 numbers (already done)
then I want to calculate the average of those 4 digits but The first digit needs to counts 1x, the second digit 2x, the third digit 3x and the fourth digit 4x. (already done)

(this is the part where i am stuck)
Also calculate the highest number. If the highest grade is more than 3 points above the average, the screen will show:

```
cheater!
-1
```

If the highest grade is less than 3 points above the average, the actual average will appear on the screen, rounded to 1 decimal place.

```
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int i;
        double sum;
        double number;
        double result = 0;

        for (i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
            number = sc.nextDouble();
            sum = number * i;
            result += sum;
            if (number%result > 3) {
                System.out.println("cheater!\n" + "-1.0");

            } else{
                System.out.printf("%3.1f", result / 10);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see above here, this is what I got for now. Don't know exactly what I am doing wrong here?

These are my input/results:

```
5.5
6.1
7.3
5.8

0.6cheater!
-1.0
cheater!
-1.0
cheater!
-1.0
```

Expected results:

Sample Input 1:

```
5.5
6.1
7.3
5.8
```

Sample Output 1:

```
6.3
```

Sample Input 2:

```
3.0
5.4
9.8
2.5
```

Sample Output 2:

```
cheater!
-1.0
```

Comment: Store the highest input in a separate field and do the comparison after the for loop where you take the inputs and based on them calculate an average. Side note __**3 points above the averag**__ sounds as if you need to substract the average from the highest input and not do a modulo operation

Comment: I think you need to save the printing and also the detection of cheating till after the loop (not inside it). Only after all numers have been input can you correctly calculate the average (so-called weighted average). This also means that underway in addition to the sum you will also need to keep track of the highest number entered.

Comment: what do you think `number%result` does ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        double sum;
        double number;
        double result = 0;
        double max = 0;

        //Compute the sum
        for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
        {
            number = sc.nextDouble();
            sum = number * i;
            result += sum;

            if (max < number)
                max = number;
        }

        //Average
        double average = Math.Round((double)result / 10, 1);

        //Compare to data
        if (max > average + 3)
            System.out.println("cheater!\n" + "-1.0");
        else
            System.out.printf("%3.1f", average);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. For reference: [Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/12567365)

Answer (score 0):

1. to calculate average you need the sum(*sum* variable) divide by amount of numbers(4 in your case)
2. you need to use array to find the highest number
3. the if logic is incorrect

I suggest:

```
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        double sum;
        double[] number = new double[4];
        double result = 0;
        double highestNum = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
            number[i] = sc.nextDouble();
            sum += number[i] * i;
            if(highestNum<number[i]){
                 highestNum = number[i];
                 }
            }
            double aveNum = sum/4;
               
            if ((highestNum-aveNum)> 3) {
                System.out.println("cheater!\n" + "-1.0");

            } else{
                System.out.printf("%3.1f", result / 10);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. A bit of nitpicking: 1. When in the average the numbers count 1x, 2x, 3x and 4x, you need to divide by the sum of those numbers, 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 = 10, not by 4. // 2. Another option is to keep track of the highest number entered so far, then you don’t need the array. // 3. Incorrectly using `%` instead of `-` may have been a typo. // Also as said in the comments I believe that the calculation of average and printing need to go outside the loop.

Comment: Can it also be done without an array? because that is the way I am trying to solve it.

Comment: *Can it also be done without an array?* Yes, @JavaStudent, it certainly can. Leave out the array, keep `number = sc.nextDouble()` from your own code and do the comparison as `if (highestNum < number) {`. You will need to adapt a little further, but there’s really no need for the array.